# PHP array insert into a table depend on each array

Tags: php, arrays

I have one Array consisting of some values. I want to insert Array with other row on each array. like:

```
$recepient = ['Alex', 'John']; 
$title= 'Hi there'; 
$body= 'Test sms';
$sdate = '2021-09-17';
```

I want my table to be some thing like this

```
+----+----------+-------------+------+--------+-------+
| id | Recepient  | Title    | Body      | Sdate      |
+----+----------+-------------+------+--------+-------+
| 1  | Alex       | Hi there | Test sms  | 2021-09-17 |
+----+----------+-------------+------+--------+-------+
| 2  | John       | Hi there | Test sms  | 2021-09-17 |
+----+----------+-------------+------+--------+-------+
```

I need some help, What will be the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Just use a `foreach` loop

Comment: Inside the loop, create an associative array with the current element of the loop and the other variables. Push that onto the result array.

Comment: Yes foreach loop, foreach( $recepient as $index => $col ){
    $query="here I fail ";
    }

Comment: Do you want to insert into a mysql database / table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple task that you should not feel so hard.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$recepient = ['Alex', 'John']; 
$title= 'Hi there'; 
$body= 'Test sms';
$sdate = '2021-09-17';


echo "<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Recepient</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th>Sdate</th>
  </tr>";
  
  $counter = 1;
  
  foreach($recepient as $recp) {
      
  echo "<tr>
  <td>".$counter++."</td>
    <td>$recp</td>
    <td>$title</td>
    <td>$body</td>
     <td>$sdate</td>
  </tr>";
  
  }
  
echo "</table>";

?>
```

**Output:**

```
ID  Recepient   Title       Body        Sdate
1   Alex        Hi there    Test sms    2021-09-17
2   John        Hi there    Test sms    2021-09-17
```

Comment: Hahaha, I was so stupid. I executed a query outside the loop. thanks for opening my eyes.